# Express.js Designing Error Handling

Tags: node.js, express, design-patterns

I'm stuck on how to design error handling in an Express.js application.
What are the best design practices to handle errors in Express?

To my understanding, I can handle errors in 2 different ways:

First way would be to use an error middleware and, when an error is thrown in a route, propagate the error to that error middleware. This means that we have to insert the logic of the error handler in the middleware itself (note, the middleware here was purposely kept simple).

```
app.post('/someapi', (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.params.id == undefined) {
       let err = new Error('ID is not defined');
       return next(err);
    }
    // do something otherwise
});    
app.use((err, req, res, next)=>{
    // some error logic
    res.status(err.status || 500).send(err);
});
```

Another option is to deal with the errors on the spot, when the error happens. This means that the logic must be in the route itself

```
app.post('/someapi', (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.params.id == undefined) {
        let err = new Error('ID is not defined');
        // possibly add some logic
        return res.status(ErrorCode).send(err.message);
    }
    // do something otherwise
});
```

What is the best approach, and what are the best design practices for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think there are much more extensive cases but the main idea is using middleware design. Add your validation logic to this middleware.

```
yourRouter.post('/message', routerValidator.messageValidator, yourController.saveMessage.bind(yourController));
```

Below is my sample structure;

// controller

```
const BaseRoute = require('../infra/base/BaseRoute');
const log = require('./../../utils/log-helper').getLogger('route-web');
const { ErrorTypes } = require('../infra/middlewares/ErrorMiddleware');
const GameService = require('../../service/GameService');
const { SystemMessages } = require('../../statics/default_types');

module.exports = class WebController {
    constructor() {
        this._logger = log;
        this._gameService = new GameService();
    }

    getGameInfo(req, res) {
        var self = this;
        try {
            const info = self._gameService.getGameInfo(req.body.query);
            return BaseRoute.success(res, { info });
        } catch (err) {
            self._logger.error('Something went wrong while getting game information', err);
            return BaseRoute.internalError(res, SystemMessages.GENERIC_ERROR, req.getErrorCode(ErrorTypes.UNHANDLED, 1));
        }
    }
};
```

// router index

```
const express = require('express');
const ErrorMiddleware = require('../infra/middlewares/ErrorMiddleware').ErrorMiddlewarePath;
const baseValidator = require('../infra/validators/BaseRouterValidator');
const AndroidController = require('./AndroidController');
const IosController = require('./IosController');
const WebController = require('./WebController');

const AndroidRouter = express.Router();
const IosRouter = express.Router();
const WebRouter = express.Router();

const androidController = new AndroidController();
const iosController = new IosController();
const webController = new WebController();

AndroidRouter.post('/message', ErrorMiddleware(1), baseValidator.teamQueryValidator, androidController.getGameInfo.bind(androidController));
IosRouter.post('/message', ErrorMiddleware(1), baseValidator.teamQueryValidator, iosController.getGameInfo.bind(iosController));
WebRouter.post('/message', ErrorMiddleware(1), baseValidator.teamQueryValidator, webController.getGameInfo.bind(webController));

module.exports = {
    AndroidRouter,
    IosRouter,
    WebRouter
};
```

// validator

```
const log = require('../../../utils/log-helper').getLogger('route-validator-base');
const BaseRoute = require('../base/BaseRoute');
const _ErrorTypes = require('../middlewares/ErrorMiddleware').ErrorTypes;

function teamQueryValidator(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body || !req.body.query) {
        const params = req.body ? JSON.stringify(req.body) : 'Empty';
        log.error('Invalid Parameters req body', params);
        return BaseRoute.httpError(res, 'Bir takım adı giriniz..', 400, req.getErrorCode(_ErrorTypes.VALIDATION, 1));
    }
    return next();
}

module.exports = {
    teamQueryValidator
};
```

// app.js that assigns to express

```
this._router = require('./src/route/api/index');        
this._ErrorMiddleware = require('./src/route/infra/middlewares/ErrorMiddleware').ErrorMiddlewareRouter;
this.app.use('/api/android', this._ErrorMiddleware(1), this._router.AndroidRouter);
this.app.use('/api/ios', this._ErrorMiddleware(2), this._router.AndroidRouter);    
this.app.use('/api/web', this._ErrorMiddleware(3), this._router.WebRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What are the best design practices to handle errors in Express?

There is no best design, it's all subjective.

> To my understanding, I can handle errors in 2 different ways:

Correct. You used error middleware for the first and then handled the error directly in the route handler.

To me, it makes sense to separate out the error handling logic from the business logic. It makes for cleaner code. So the former (error middleware) would be better IMO.

You would have a different error handler for different errors.